# System crash after setting wlan in interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless, crash

I'm trying to set a script `script.sh` to run when wlan connects. After some research I've come up with the following `/etc/network/interfaces`:

> ```
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto wlan0
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp 
>     wireless-essid ANY
>     wireless-mode managed
>     post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/script.sh
> ```

However, when I want to test this configuration and run

`sudo service networking restart`

The system crashes with no error message, I don't even have access to any tty.

This is an excerpt of my system log `/etc/var/syslog`: http://pastebin.com/1g2eJfjD

**System details**

> lsb_release -a
>
> ```
> ...
> Description:  Ubuntu 13.10
> Release:  13.10
> Codename: saucy
> ```
>
> uname -a
>
> ```
> ... 3.11.0-26-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP ... x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```